# Django Zinnia cannot link to "weblog" within home page

Tags: python, html, django, zinnia

I'm using the Django Edge (v2.0) template, and have created a site, this is my main project and it's titled: Website. Within the project, I set out to implement a blog, and installed Zinnia. I have the following:

Python 3.4.2 and Django 1.7.7

I installed Zinnia per the installation documents, including all listed dependencies, and it works. If I navigate to 127.0.0.0, it takes me to the "home page" of the Website project. If I navigate 127.0.0.0/weblog/, it'll take me to the Zinnia's "home page" of the blog. This all works. However, on the Website's homepage (home.html), I'm trying to create a link to the /weblog, but can't seem to make it work. I'm sure it's just syntax, and my lack of knowledge.

Here's how my project is structured:

```
├── LICENSE.txt
├── README.md
├── docs
│   └── index.md
├── requirements.txt
└── src
    ├── Website
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── settings
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   ├── views.py
    │   └── wsgi.py
    ├── accounts
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── templates
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   └── views.py
    ├── manage.py
    ├── profiles
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── templates
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   └── views.py
    ├── static
    │   ├── bootstrap
    │   └── site
    ├── templates
    │   ├── about.html
    │   ├── base.html
    │   ├── home.html
    └── zinnia
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── __pycache__
        ├── managers.py
        ├── markups.py
        ├── static
        ├── templates
        ├── urls
        ├── views
```

Here is my main's urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^$', views.HomePage.as_view(), name='home'),
    url(r'^', include(accounts.urls, namespace='accounts')),
    url(r'^users/', include(profiles.urls, namespace='profiles')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^weblog/', include('zinnia.urls', namespace='zinnia')),
    url(r'^comments/', include('django_comments.urls')),

)
```

On the Website's home, using home.html, I can create buttons that will direct me to other pages like so:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'accounts:login' %}" role="button">Log in</a>
```

I basically want a "blog" button, on my home page, that will redirect me to 127.0.0.0/weblog/, so I do this in the same fashion:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'zinnia:weblog' %}" role="button">Blog</a>
```

I get this error:

```
Reverse for 'weblog' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

With more info:

```
In template /Website/src/templates/home.html, error at line 59
59       <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'zinnia:weblog' %}" role="button">Log in</a>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am probably late, but just in case anybody needs this, here is how you get the url for the root of your weblog

```
<a href="{% url 'zinnia:entry_archive_index' %}">Weblog</a>
```